# MVC5 URL Mismatch works on localhost but not on remote machine

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, ip, localhost

I have deployed an MVC Webapplication on IIS. It works fine from VisualStudio when i hit run (F5). The Url looks something like

Home page:
`localhost:8080/`

Second Page to be displayed when Data in entered and login button clicked[Just a simple form] -> localhost:8080/Data/Query/?fname=Markus&lname=Jennings

That was visual studio. Where the view is rendered perfectly and things work as expected.

Now, when I access the  webapp from my browser by manually typing "localhost" the scenario is something like this:

Home Page:

```
localhost/website
```

Second page:

```
localhost/website/Data/Query/?fname=Markus&lname=Jennings
```

As you can see the **website** word/directory is always there. My application is published inside 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website So, I kinda understand why the website word is there. 
**Data** is my controller and **Query** is my action method.

Now comes the tricky part:

When I try to access my website using same machine but with different url (viz My IP number) the following happens

`a.b.c.d/patinput` 
Home page is rendered. 
After entering the data and hitting login, the URL that is displayed is:

```
a.b.c.d/Data/Query/?fname=Markus&lname=Jennings
```

As you might have guessed the "website" directory is not present in the URL. According to me it should have looked like

```
a.b.c.d/website/Data/Query/?fname=Markus&lname=Jennings
```

And if I manually add the website path/word, the second page is rendered as required.

The first page is a simple login form where I take the first name and last name as inputs and call a javascript function. From the Javascript function i call my Controller (Data) with the parameters retrieved from the HTML page.

Inside the javascript function I am using

```
window.location.href = '/Data/Query/?fname=' + fname + '&lname=' + lname;
```

I have tried addind a '.' before /Data/Query..... Doesn't work either.

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is nothing to do with the code. You should properly configure IIS so there shouldn't be any need to add "website" to the path.

Comment: I can see the virtual directory not being set when accessed from outside world. I tried launching the web app via VS2013 (On localhost rather than IIS Express) It works flawlessly. However when I try accessing the website from chrome on my machine or other machine, it fails. The redirection JUST DOES NOT WORK!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by a workaround. Looks something like this. 
In my javascript, I have saved the window.location.href value on the first hit. Used localStorage as

localStorage.setItem("baseUrl", window.location.href);

and whenever i want to navigate to some other Actionresult i simply append it using this baseUrl